# across process boundary in scoped_session

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy, python-multiprocessing

I'm using SQLAlchemy and multiprocessing. I also use scoped_session sinse it avoids share the same session but I've found an error and their solution but  I don't understand why does it happend.

You can see my code below:

**db.py**

```
engine = create_engine(connection_string)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
DBSession = scoped_session(Session)
```

**script.py**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process
from db import DBSession

def process_feed(test):
    session = DBSession()
    print(current_process().name, session)

def run():
    session = DBSession()
    pool = Pool()
    print(current_process().name, session)
    pool.map_async(process_feed, [1, 2]).get()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

When I run `script.py` The output is:

```
MainProcess <sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0xb707b14c>
ForkPoolWorker-1 <sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0xb707b14c>
ForkPoolWorker-2 <sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0xb707b14c>
```

Note that session object is the same `0xb707b14c` in the main process and their workers (child process)

BUT If I change the order of first two lines run():

```
def run():
    pool = Pool() # <--- Now pool is instanced in the first line
    session = DBSession()  # <--- Now session is instanced in the second line
    print(current_process().name, session)
    pool.map_async(process_feed, [1, 2]).get()
```

And the I run `script.py` again the output is:

```
MainProcess <sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0xb66907cc>
ForkPoolWorker-1 <sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0xb669046c>
ForkPoolWorker-2 <sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0xb66905ec>
```

Now the session instances are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand why this happens, you need to understand what `scoped_session` and `Pool` actually does. `scoped_session` keeps a registry of sessions so that the following happens

- the first time you call `DBSession`, it creates a `Session` object for you in the registry
- subsequently, if necessary conditions are met (i.e. same thread, session has not been closed), it does not create a new `Session` object and instead returns you the previously created `Session` object back

When you create a `Pool`, it creates the workers in the `__init__` method. (Note that there's nothing fundamental about starting the worker processes in `__init__`. An equally valid implementation could wait until workers are first needed before it starts them, which would exhibit different behavior in your example.) When this happens (on Unix), the parent process *forks* itself for every worker process, which involves the operating system copying the memory of the current running process into a new process, so you will literally get the exact same objects in the exact same places.

Putting these two together, in the first example you are creating a `Session` before forking, which gets copied over to all worker processes during the creation of the `Pool`, resulting in the same identity, while in the second example you delay the creation of the `Session` object until after the worker processes have started, resulting in different identities.

It's important to note that while the `Session` objects share the same `id`, they are *not* the same object, in the sense that if you change anything about the `Session` in the parent process, they will not be reflected in the child processes. They just happen to all share the same memory address due to the fork. *However*, OS-level resources like connections *are* shared, so if you had run a query on `session` before `Pool()`, a connection would have been created for you in the connection pool and subsequently forked into the child processes. If you then attempt to perform queries in the child processes you will run into weird errors because your processes are clobbering over each other over the same exact connection!

The above is moot for Windows because Windows does not have `fork()`.

Comment: Thank you! your explanation is very clear. But I thought that the fork is doing here: `pool.map_async(process_feed, [1, 2]).get()`

Comment: @Overflow012 Yup, that's an equally valid assumption because the documentation does not prescribe it one way or another, but, as an implenetation detail, It happens [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5affd23e6f42125998724787025080a24839266e/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L174) in `Pool.__init__`.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#using-connection-pools-with-multiprocessing

Answer (score 0):

> TCP connections are represented as file descriptors, which usually work across process boundaries, meaning this will cause concurrent access to the file descriptor on behalf of two or more entirely independent Python interpreter states.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#using-connection-pools-with-multiprocessing